# converting infopath (xml) file into PDF and sending email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow, sharepoint-on-prem

we trying to explore infopath(xml) files convert into PDF. We had SharePoint list with custom infopath. Daily users submit the form for access. our goal was when user submitted the form, its need to convert into PDF form and then that PDF file need to send IT Team via email. Means first xml file need to convert PDF and then sending email with PDF file. Is it possible to infopath only (or) SharePoint workflow need it? Can anyone share guidance how to achieve our request.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this for SharePoint on-premise or for SharePoint Online?

Comment: SP 2013 enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

Let's address emailing of attachments first. In SharePoint on-premise, there is no out-of-the-box way to send email attachments. At best you can use the appropriate workflow action to send an email with a link to the file.

Third party products, e.g. Nintex Workflow do support sending emails with attachments. Also, if you don't mind [setting up a gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/gateway-reference), you can [use Microsoft Flow to send emails with attachments](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2016/10/attach-converted-pdf-files-to-email.html).

With regards to your other point, converting InfoPath XML to PDF. I am an expert in this field as the company I work for actually creates an InfoPath to PDF Converter. Let's just say that it is EXTREMELY tricky to create a reliable PDF Converter that works in a server (or any other kind of) environment.

So here comes a shameless plug, although I cannot think of another viable option other than coding away for the better part of a year. Check out [this blog post and white paper](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2016/10/converting-infopath-to-pdf-is-still.html).

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you are using InfoPath with code behind you will be able to to achieve that with custom coding. If not you can either add that functionality with code behind (on submit event) or use Workflow.

Comment: Could you please share some steps how to achive.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to check out [Formotus forms](https://support.formotus.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002799566-How-to-customize-your-PDF) which can submit your InfoPath forms as a PDF.